# setting a message attribute of a message in an SQS queue w/boto?

Tags: boto, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to set a message attribute of a message in an SQS queue?  I am trying to examine a message sent to an SQS queue and change its value.  The last line of the code below gets and prints the value.

```
for message in queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10, AttributeNames=['All'], MessageAttributeNames=['All']):
    print(message.body)
    print(message.attributes)
    print(message.message_attributes)
    print(message.message_attributes.get('attr').get('StringValue'))
```

I would like a way of setting the **StringValue** of **attr** in this message.  Is there any way of doing that?  I would prefer a way of doing this using **boto** (rather than **boto3**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message attributes of an SQS message are immutable once the message has been sent to the queue.  The SQS Query API (used by all client libraries) has no support for modifying a message in the queue, other than to change its visibility timeout.